Rust Analyzer Not Appearing in VSCode Status Bar
I am having an issue with Rust Analyzer in Visual Studio Code. Despite installing Rust Analyzer and configuring the settings, it does not appear in the status bar. Here are the steps I have taken so far:

Installed Rust Analyzer via the VSCode marketplace.

Added the following configuration to my settings.json file:
"[rust]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "rust-lang.rust-analyzer",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.inlayHints.enabled": "off"
}



However, Rust Analyzer still does not show up in the status bar, and I am not receiving any of its features.
I would appreciate any guidance on how to resolve this issue.

not appearing on status bar
